# why does this keep saying it's not definied

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

Using firebug it keeps stating that this.speak is not defined and I don't understand why that is.I am trying to output it to the screen

```
 $(document).ready (function() {


    function person(rank, number, id) {
        //properties
        this.intRank = rank;
        this.intNumber = number;
        this.strId = id;
        this.elOutput = document.getElementById(id);
        //methods
        this.speak = fucntion(); {
            this.elOutput.innerHTML += "<br>" + this.strId;
        };

        //adds one to int number and speaks message
        this.pickUpNumber = function() {
            this.intNumber++;
            this.strId = "i have" + this.intNumber.toString() + "rocks";
            this.speak();
        };
    };

    //object

    var Jak = new person(5, "hey ,jack", " Captain");
    var Cap = new person(3, "yea cap?", "jacko");

    jak.speak(); cap.speak(); jak.pickUpRock();

});
```

Comment: typo `this.speak = fucntion` ==> `function`

Comment: Also the semicolon after `fucntion` is misplaced, and your `Jak` and `Cap` variable should be lowercase like in the method invocations following their declarations.

Comment: Keep in mind, in javascript `this.speak = function();` with the semicolon right after, terminates your function statement before its even defined. Thus it will always be `undefined`

Comment: @element11: This is actually a syntax error. The code won't even be executed.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. It cannot run at all. How can the debugger tell you that `this.speak` is `undefined` if the code is not even executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.speak = fucntion(); {
  this.elOutput.innerHTML += "<br>" + this.strId;
};
```

I think you mean **`function()`**

And JS is case sensitive.

Probably this is what you tried to accomplish:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    function person(rank, number, id) {
      //properties
      this.intRank = rank;
      this.intNumber = number;
      this.strId = id;
      this.elOutput = document.getElementById(id);


      //methods
      this.speak = function() {
        this.elOutput.innerHTML += "<br>" + this.strId;
      };

      //adds one to int number and speaks message
      this.pickUpNumber = function() {
        this.intNumber++;
        this.strId = "i have" + this.intNumber.toString() + "rocks";
        this.speak();
      };
    }

    //object

    var jak = new person(5, "hey ,jack", " Captain");
    var cap = new person(3, "yea cap?", "jacko");

    jak.speak(); cap.speak(); jak.pickUpNumber();
});
```

Checkout [this](http://jsbin.com/pojilozeve/1/edit?html,js,console,output) working jsbin

Comment: This should be an edit

Comment: @Lux No, this is literally the answer. Among a few other typos.

Comment: If that is really the issue, how can the debugger say that `this.speak` is `undefined`? The code cannot even be executed if there is a syntax error.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. He is saying that this.speak should be defined as the function fucntion(), which he may have defined himself elsewhere. If he had not but the semicolon after it, then it would have caught the error.

Comment: @Worthy7—while it's possible that the OP has created a function `function fucntion(){...}` or `var fucntion = function(){...}` the likelihood is extremely small. Similarly, `jak.speak` should throw a reference error since *jak* is not defined, but there is no report of that.